# rodata on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, gcc, linker, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a simple printf function on my bare metal OS for the Raspberry Pi.

The function is empty right now:

```
int kprintf(const char *string, ...) {
}
```

Currently, I am able to draw to the screen. However, I run into problems when calling this function.
As a test, I draw a few characters to the screen before calling kprintf.

If I use:

```
kprintf ("HELLO");
```

The screen is blank. However, if I use:

```
kprintf ("HE");
```

Everything is OK. The only thing I can think of at this point is that there must be a problem with the linker script. Perhaps the rodata section.

I am using a modified linker script from the Cambridge RPi tutorials:

```
STARTUP(crt0.o)

SECTIONS {
    .init 0x8000 : {
        *(.init)
    }

    .text 0x8080 : {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
        *(COMMON)
    }

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(*)
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, seems OK if I use this linker script:

```
STARTUP(crt0.o)

SECTIONS {
    .init 0x8000 : {
        *(.init)
    }

    .text 0x9000 : {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
        *(COMMON)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(*)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else in future